# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2012 generate a EDM diagram from my MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

What I have done:

1. Create a mysql database with user that has all rights
2. Install visual studio 2012 add-in for mysql
3. Install ADO.NET connector for mysql
4. Create a console application project (.NET 4.0) in visual studio 2012
   4.1 -> reference mysql.data and mysql.data.entity
5. Create new ADO.Net Entity Data Model
6. Choose Generate from Database and fill in the connection properties (EF 5)
7. Select the tables / views
8. Finish

Now, VS2012 generates the edmx file, but it does not generate a diagram. When I check the entities, I find out that it doesn't even create the tables/views as entities.

Am I missing something in this setup?

**UPDATE**
This is my .edmx.diagram

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
 <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram DiagramId="7c3c63f951954ff88783612f28edb5f2" Name="Diagram1" />
    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: how you have checked that does not generate a diagram

Comment: Try this extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. There was a bug in the entity model designer that has been fixed.

[This reference should provides details, but I can't find the fix yet.](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1173)